# converting python list of integers to a hex number

Tags: python

I have library function which reads from hardware and returns

```
value = readregister(registerindex,numbytes)
```

where `value` is a python list.

If `numbytes` is 2, then the complete returned number will be returned in

```
value[0],value[1]
```

For example it returns

```
    [128,2]
```

which in hex is

```
   [0x80,0x2]
```

How do I convert this list value of 2 elements to a hex python number ? 
So if combine them I should get 0x280 ie 640

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_conversion

Comment: Why ask to get to get the hex format when what you really want is to convert the bytes to a single number.

Comment: `hex(128 + (2 * 256))` will do it... or `hex(value[0] + (256 * value[1]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to convert to an intermediate hex representation. You can just left shift the bits to create the number you want.

```
def get_number(values):
    total = 0
    for val in reversed(values):
        total = (total << 8) + val
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
list=[128,2]
>>> b=[]
>>> for item in list:
...     b.append(hex(item))
... 
>>> b
>>>[0x80,0x2]
```

Comment: Or just `print(list(map(hex,[128,2])))`. having a list called list is not a very good idea though.

Comment: the question is how to convert a list to a number

Comment: @Avinash your answer is incomplete.The  final output should be of this sort: val = 0x280 or val = 640